# Optimize shuffling an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, optimization, arraylist

The problem is this: I need to shuffle a deck of cards (ArrayList or array of 52 ints (0 to 51)). I also need to do this 200,000 times and on an Android processor. Please help me optimize this, because this is taking an unbelievable amount of time even on a more high end device (up to 10 seconds).

Methods I've tried:

1) Shuffle the deck with Collections.shuffle and draw first cards I get (takes 8 seconds on Nexus7):

```
for(long i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) { // ITERATIONS is 200,000
        ArrayList<Integer> fakeDeck = (ArrayList) deck.clone(); // deck is the sorted deck.
        Collections.shuffle(fakeDeck);
        int card1 = fakeDeck.get(0);
        int card2 = fakeDeck.get(1);
        int card3 = fakeDeck.get(2);
        int card4 = fakeDeck.get(3);
        int card5 = fakeDeck.get(4);
        // do something with cards.
}
```

2) Randomly pick cards from an unshuffled deck (a bit better, takes 5 secs):

```
for(long i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) { // ITERATIONS is 200,000
        ArrayList<Integer> fakeDeck = (ArrayList) deck.clone(); // deck is the sorted deck.
        int card1 = pullCardFromDeck(fakeDeck);
        int card2 = pullCardFromDeck(fakeDeck);
        int card3 = pullCardFromDeck(fakeDeck);
        int card4 = pullCardFromDeck(fakeDeck);
        int card5 = pullCardFromDeck(fakeDeck);
        // do something with cards.
}
```

// pullCardFromDeck is:

```
private int pullCardFromDeck(ArrayList<Integer> deck) {
    int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(deck.size());
    int card = deck.get(randomNumber); // get a random card.
    deck.remove(randomNumber); // remove the card from the deck.
    return card;
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to clone the deck each time?

Comment: In the 1st example it's not necesssary, I can reshuffle the same deck, in the second example I need to, becuase I remove cards. But that really is not the issue, as the cloning takes a meager amount of time compared to the shuffling.

Comment: `Random`s aren't cheap to make. Move it outside of your loop and pass it in to your method.

Comment: `I also need to do this 200,000 times and on an Android processor.` Why? Also, why shuffle the whole deck? Can't you just pull random cards from it when they're needed?

Comment: I need to calculate poker odds exhaustively. I can pull random cards, the second example does just that.

Comment: @VM Maybe explain why 200,000 times. Unless you are running a Monte Carlo simulation of something I can't find a reason.

Comment: Well yes, I'm dealing 200,000 different community boards to figure out how many times a player wins.

Comment: *"as the cloning takes a meager amount of time compared to the shuffling"* And you determined this through benchmarks...right?

Comment: I'm using System.nanoTime(); and compounding the time my method is taking, removing the cloning from the timing does not impact time taken severely.

Comment: Can you show what exactly you're measuring? Perhaps you could get rid of cloning the array and removing the elements. It may be faster just to keep a list of up to 5 indices of the cards used in a single draw (effectively marking the cards as already in use instead of actually removing them from the deck).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need five cards you could just shuffle 5 cards each time. This could be 20x faster.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    int[] cards = new int[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) cards[i] = i;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int runs = 1000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        shuffleN(cards, 5);
        int card1 = cards[0], card2 = cards[1], card3 = cards[2], card4 = cards[3], card5 = cards[4];
    }
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to shuffle %,d times%n", time / 1e3, runs);
}

private static final Random RND = new Random();

public static void shuffleN(int[] numbers, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int r = RND.nextInt(numbers.length - i) + i;
        if (i == r) continue;
        int tmp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[r];
        numbers[r] = tmp;
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 0.115 seconds to shuffle 1,000,000 times
```

Comment: I need to draw 5 cards from a 52 card deck.

Comment: @VM So you would make the count 5, and the top 5 cards would be random, even if the rest of the cards would not be very random. i.e. this is like a shuffle but stops after the first 5 cards, making it possibly 10x faster.

Comment: I don't understand, won't you be interchanging the same 5 cards every time? That would yield the same result. Sorry I'm slow.

Comment: @VM This is swapping five random cards from the whole deck and placing them at the top.  The first five will be random, the remaining 47 will be the rest.  The next time, 5 are chosen at random from the 52, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off considering using an index of int[] that you shuffle and use to access a single deck.  For getting random entries, set the chosen index to zero (and when you get a random number see if the value is already zero, if it is choose a new card)